# Simple e equation

Tags: exponential-function

> $$e^{-x}-x+1=0$$

$$\frac{1}{e^x}=x-1$$

$$e^x(x-1) = 1$$

$$\therefore e^x = 1, x-1 = 1$$
Where
$$x=0, x=2$$
Or,
$$e^x = -1, x-1 = -1$$
Where
$$x=nil,x=0 $$

Therefore, there is no solution to the equation. However, plotting the initial curve gives me one x-intercept at x = 1.28 => Why so?

Comment: You cant do so comparing with $1$

Comment: How does $e^x(x-1)=1$ imply that their values are $(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$?

Comment: Because only 1*1 and -1*-1 give 1?

Comment: $e\times \frac{1}{e}=1$, therefore $e=1$. Hmmm....

Comment: Haha! What about multiplicative inverses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method for solving this equation is wrong. The equation
$$e^x(x-1)=1$$
is correct, but you can't deduce much from it. In particular, you seem to have factored $1$ in the integers and said that either both factors are $1$ or $-1$. This would work if they work both integers - or, in fact, if *either* was an integer - and establishes that there are no integer solutions. However, we can have things like $1=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2 \cdot \sqrt{2}$ where $1$ is written as a product in other ways, and your solution fails to account for that. Indeed, for any $x$ other than zero, we have $x\cdot \frac{1}x=1$, so you've missed a lot of solutions when you worked only in the integers. Thus, it shouldn't surprise us too much that there might be a non-integer solution, which is what you're seeing on the graph.

The trouble is that this equation has no solution in terms of elementary functions, as far as I know. One can solve it using the [product log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function $W$, which has the property that $W(y)e^{W(y)}=y$ - that is, it's the inverse function to $xe^x$. Using this we first divide both sides by $e$:
$$e^{x-1}(x-1)=\frac{1}e$$
Then apply the product log:
$$x-1 = W\left(\frac{1}e\right)$$
$$x=W\left(\frac{1}e\right)+1$$
which is the root visible on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Hint you can use approximations here ie $e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}...$ till first four -five terms and then get roots. (Though its a very tidious work) .